# How to create interface annotation that implements PreAuthorize which uses values from the interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created my own flexible permission interface that implements `@PreAuthorize` annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.hasPermission(authentication.principal, " + "@HasUserPermission.firstType(), " + "@HasUserPermission.secondType()")
public @interface HasUserPermission {
    String firstType() default "";
    String secondType() default "";

}
```

I expect that `hasPermission` will use the `firstType()` and `secondType()` values of `@interface` to call 'hasPermission' but don't do nothing and I didn't find any solution or idea for my problem.
How can I pass `firstType()` and `secondType()` to `@PreAuthorize` ? Is it possible ?